# CSS inside areas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about Bootstrap. I would like to know if you could let the `style` HTML code work in a specified area. I have this code, and I would like the following CSS code to work only in this div.

HTML CODE:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:280px;">
    <a class="pull-left" style="position:relative; margin: 4px 5px 0 0;">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://minotar.net/avatar/mcname/32.png" player="mcname" size="32" width="32" height="32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; vertical-align: bottom;" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="color: red"><b>Marcus</b></a>
    <span class="label" style="background-color: green; color: white"><a href="#" class="nounderline">Owner</a></span>
    <span class="label" style="background-color: purple; color: white"><a href="#" class="nounderline">Developer</a></span>
    <span class="label" style="background-color: #FA0; color: white"><a href="#" class="nounderline">Staff</a></span>
    <p><i>Posted Nov. 16'th, 2013</i></p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE: (I put it in the HTML code with the `style`)

```
a {
    color: inherit;
}
a:hover { 
    color: white
}
a:link { 
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-decoration: none
}
```

> ## EDIT:
>
> I've tried all the answers, but strange enough, they aren't working. In my head they looked like they were right, and they must have. I can't just get it to work. When I try the answers the links all around the page fade from white to it's normal color. I just want the div with the label span's to show links as white (also with hover), and everything else on the page as normal Bootstrap links.
>   - Even thought it doesn't work for me, thanks to you guys for trying to help me!

Comment: id the div, reference child elements with id

Comment: @Rooster what do you mean? I've allready tried to put the style in the div, but it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the parent div an id, and then reference its child. An example:

```
<div id="Parent">
  <span>I should be given unique style!<span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Parent span {
    /* my style goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...  let the style HTML code work ... is quite unclear.

If you want to apply a refered style sheet or a `<style block>` to a specific part of a web document, you can achieve this by using the 'scoped' `<style attribute>`

http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

> The scoped attribute is a boolean attribute. If set, it indicates that the styles are intended just for the subtree rooted at the style
>   element’s parent element, as opposed to the whole Document.
>       — WHATWG

---

an example :

```
<article>
  <h1>Style Scoped</h1>
  <p>The scoped attribute for the style element will eventually allow for you to include style elements mid-document. To do this, you must mark up your style element with the scoped attribute.</p>
  <section>
    <style scoped>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
    <h2>How does it work?</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

source : http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

**[ cross browser warning ]**

- http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped

---

For the 'other' suggestion, try studying [CSS CASCADE PRECEDENCE](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) (The 6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity part).

> Some examples:
>
> - ***           {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,0,0 */
> - li            {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,0,1 */
> - li:first-line {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
> - ul li         {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
> - ul ol+li      {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,0,3 */
> - h1 + *[rel=up]{}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
> - ul ol li.red  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,1,3 */
> - li.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,2,1 */
> - #x34y         {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
> - style=""          /* a=1 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 1,0,0,0 */

```
.style { /* some css applied to an element with selector .style */ }
.style .child { /* some css applied to an element child of .style with selector .child */ }
.style [element] { /* some css applied to an element child of .style */ }
.parent-selector .children-selector { /* and so on */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a mix of inline, internal and external CSS styles.  Ideally, should be using only external styles, and use internal and inline CSS only when it's absolutely necessary.  This creates cleaner code that is more organized and easier to work with.  The Bootstrap framework you are using is pretty much nothing but external CSS files.  You can look at them to see how they work, and I would suggest checking out [this link](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/applyingcss/) to learn the different ways you can apply CSS.

Your specific problem, at the moment, deals with inheritance, which you can solve with [nested CSS classes](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/).

What you want to do is create a CSS class and tell your 'a' tags to inherit from it, like this:

```
.myclass > a {

}
```

The angle bracket tells the 'a' tag to inherit from whatever is above it.  In CSS, this is called nesting.

You will have to create a different nest for each a tag.  Do this, and write your styles into them.

```
.myclass > a {
    color: inherit;
}

.myclass > a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.myclass > a:link {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then make sure you apply the class to your 'div' tag like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
```

Finally, make sure your inline styles aren't overriding any of your classes.  For example, this anchor has a color defined as an inline stlye.  This inline style will override the styles specified from the classes we have created:

```
<a href="#" style="color: red"><b>Marcus</b></a>
```

To fix this, just get rid of the inline style, and the nested CSS that we wrote should take care of it.  Do the same for any other inline styles that may be overriding your classes.

[HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/) is a great place to learn more about HTML, CSS and Javascript.  Check it out :)

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now that I look at this again.  Although I suggest learning how to place your styles in an external CSS file, that's not your issue.  You are using inline styles on all of your elements.  Inline styles will affect only the element to which you apply them.  What you want to do is create classes.  Classes allow you to reuse styles on multiple elements, and they make it easy to allow child elements inherit styles from parent elements, like I explained above.  Let me modify my answer to show you what I mean now that I have a better idea of the problem.

Comment: How could I then add the CSS code I was talking about? I knew about the style color, but the whole CSS code can it be in there?

Comment: Can it be in where?  Are you talking about the style attribute or the style element? The style in <style></style> is an element and the style in <a style=""> is an attribute of the 'a' element.

Comment: Can I just put my style in like this?;
<a style="a {
    color: inherit;
}
a:hover { color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none}
a:link { color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none}"></a style>

Comment: Nope.  I can see how that's confusing, though.  When you use the <style type="text/css"></style> element, you are either going to write internal CSS classes inside that element (like I did in my example) or you are going to use it to link to an external stylesheet like this <style type="text/css" href="whereever-the-file-is.css"></style>.  However, when you use the style attribute, as in <a style=""></a> or <div style=""></div>, you aren't writing CSS, you are applying CSS.

Comment: I can't see how that could make a specified CSS for only a div. Am I just stupid, or do I have something right?

Comment: Ha, no you're not stupid.  CSS can be difficult to understand if you've never worked with it before.  At this point, though, it sounds like you really need to cover your basics before jumping into writing any more.  I would strongly recommend reading through those tutorials I linked you to.  Start at the beginner level and go from there.  Check out google and youtube for CSS tutorials, too.  There are tons of them out there :)